# The theme goes insane after install snap themes

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-theme

hope you are doing well.
I have a problem after I install the snap theme on moodle app. I have the latest update for both moodle and the plugin everything is okay and I'm hosting on a shared server on Namecheap. I will post a picture below about what is happing when I select the snap theme.
also, all my PHP are up to date with Cpanel

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

and at the end of the page this appears:

Picture 3:
[image]

Anyone can help me fix this

Comment: Looks like it doesnt find style file.

Comment: I download the theme zip file from Moodle plugin and install the plugin everything is okay, but when I select the theme it goes like above pictures